# webpack config for haml

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-loader

So I've just started using webpack for my projects. I am using webpack to try and compile my haml templates to jsx to react elements. To do this I am using the haml-jsx and babel-loader loaders.

so, the problem I'm having right now arises when webpack goes to load the .haml template. I keep getting this error "module parse failed: unexpected token. you may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type". idk what is preventing the haml-jsx loader from working right, but as I said I'm new to webpack so idk if it's my webpack config file or something outside of that. That's why I'm coming to you folks!

**the following is my webpack config file:**

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry:path.resolve(__dirname,"index.js"),
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test:/\.haml$/,
                use:[
                    {
                        loader:"babel-loader",
                        options:{
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                            plugins: [require('@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx')]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader:"haml-jsx-loader"
                    }
                ]   
            },
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename:"bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,"/distro")
    },
};
```

**also my directory structure looks like this**

```
webpack
-sass(dir)
-distro(dir)
-haml(dir)
  -tamplate.haml
-node_modules
-webpack.config.js
-babel.config.js
-index.js
-package.json
```

any suggestions at all would help! thanks!

Comment: Please, create a minimal repo that reproduces the problem.

Comment: What version of webpack are you using? Also can you post entire stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Can you replace `loader:"haml-jsx-loader"` with `loader:"haml-jsx"` and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

The issue does not have anything to do with *haml* itself. The loaders are fine, except of the fact, that one of them can not parse - and therefore load - the given file.

Having a look at your babel-loader config, the fact that you're using React is the key to your issue. [`@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx) is **not** what you're looking for. You should be using [`@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx.html).

To be honest, the documentation for all the babel plugins is pretty bad actually.